# How to save progress in a quiz app in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm building a quiz app in flutter but I was searching for a way to save my progress in the quiz so if I close the app during the quiz I don't have to start it from the beginning and only go back to where I stopped

Comment: Add an example of the data you wish to save, such as an object or list.

Comment: I just wanted the user to continue the quiz from where he stopped when closed the app

Comment: I understand that part, but it is important to know how big the data is that needs to be saved. Is it an integer?

Comment: Yup integer 
the app display the question by number so let's assume He is in Q5 the function will be displaying the fifth element in my questions list, so the next time he opens the app the function will be displaying the fifth element in the lest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're saving something simple like an integer or string I suggest using the [Shared Preferences Package](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)

Here is a working example:

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'SharedPreferences Demo',
      home: SharedPreferencesDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class SharedPreferencesDemo extends StatefulWidget {
  SharedPreferencesDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  SharedPreferencesDemoState createState() => SharedPreferencesDemoState();
}

class SharedPreferencesDemoState extends State<SharedPreferencesDemo> {
  Future<SharedPreferences> _prefs = SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  Future<int> _counter;

  Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await _prefs;
    final int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;

    setState(() {
      _counter = prefs.setInt("counter", counter).then((bool success) {
        return counter;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _counter = _prefs.then((SharedPreferences prefs) {
      return (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("SharedPreferences Demo"),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<int>(
              future: _counter,
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
                switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                  case ConnectionState.waiting:
                    return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                  default:
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                    } else {
                      return Text(
                        'Button tapped ${snapshot.data} time${snapshot.data == 1 ? '' : 's'}.\n\n'
                        'This should persist across restarts.',
                      );
                    }
                }
              })),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [shared_preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) package for string data such as int, bool, and char

A very simple for implementing code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        child: Text('Increment Counter'),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_incrementCounter() async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  int counter = (prefs.getInt('counter') ?? 0) + 1;
  print('Pressed $counter times.');
  await prefs.setInt('counter', counter);
}
```

for more check the package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)